# Is there safe way to remove a .ldf file without losing database data?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a database which in stuck "in recovery" mode. The .ldf file is very large and the free disk space is very low. I suspect that the large size of the .ldf file is causing the database to be stuck "in recovery"  mode.

The question: Is there a safe way of removing the .ldf file without losing database data?

Comment: Were you recovering a backup when it happened? If so, add the recovery command you used. And what is the size of the .ldf file?

Comment: @Ronaldo No i was not recovering a backup.

Comment: What happened right before it was in recovery mode?...Did you restart the service or server?...and/or kill a long running transaction?

Comment: @AMtwo I have visited previously that questions several times, but it did not answer my question :(

Comment: Until you provide answers to the questions posed to you, we cannot offer further advice. Voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

You want to consult the errorlog file to see the status of the recovery process.

"In recovery" means that is is starting up the database (you might have re-started your SQL Server or attached a database, for instance) and it need to get it into a clean state. If this state persists longer that a minute, then it is likely performing a huge rollback. Just wait it out. You can't delete the ldf as long as SQL server is running. If you stop SQL Server and delete the ldf, then you will get into below state:

"Recovery pending". This means that recovery failed and it is time to perform a restore. I have a feeling that you prefer to wait out the recovery process (above paragraph).

A risk is that the ldf file need to grow during recovery and you this grow fails. So  investigate if you can free up disk space by some other means to stop that from happening.

Answer (score 2):

If your log has uncommitted transactions, you either need to wait for recovery to complete (which, yeah, can take a long time, depending on the transactions that have to be recovered), or you lose that data. There is no other way to get that data that's in the transaction log except through the recovery process.

The good news is, your MDF file(s) is fine. If you want to completely toss the data that's in the log (stuff in flight, inserts, deletes, updates), then you can follow [one of the paths outlined in this article](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-rebuild-a-database-with-a-corrupted-or-deleted-sql-server-transaction-log-file/) to rebuild your log file. That will get your database back online, but without the data from the log.

Comment: ... and we should probably emphasize that the rebuld that the article suggest should be a very very last resort, since you never know what state the database is in after such a rebuild. It is probably better than forever losing the database, but now somebody want to clean up the potential mess that the database is in...

Comment: No arguments from me.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Tibor and Grant have written, I would also check what is your database recovery model by right-clicking  Database->Properties->Options recovery mode and if it is FULL, how / if are you backing up transaction log regularly. Because if you have recovery model: FULL and are not backing up your transaction log, it grows, grows and grows ... UNTIL you carry out at least 1 full backup and 1 transaction log backup (long story short: backing up T-LOG enables the space re-usage so the log does not grow forever).

Comment: I have googled information about backing up transaction logs. I understand that back up truncates the original file. My question is: what is happening to original log data? Is it copied somewhere?

Comment: Hi, once you back your transaction log up, the data resides in the backup files (usually with .trn extension) and the original content of the transaction log, thanks to the backup, can be re-used (re-written). More about it e.g. here: [link](https://www.sqlshack.com/beginners-guide-sql-server-transaction-logs/). Please up-vote useful comments.